# angularjs verify duplicate and set bigger duplicate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, duplicates

I have this code, where I am checking for duplicates, it has isDuplicate boolean if it is duplicate, but I want to extend my code and compare another property, which is colorId and set isBigger property, for the bigger one :)
Do you have some suggestions?
thank you so much

here is my code:

```
$scope.verifyDuplicate = function() {
  var names = [{
    "order": 1,
    "name": "a",
    "shortName": "a",
    "isDuplicate": false,
    "categoryId": 15070,
    "colorId": 50
  }, {
    "order": 2,
    "name": "s",
    "shortName": "s",
    "categoryId": 15071,
    "colorId": 51
  }, {
    "order": 3,
    "name": "h",
    "shortName": "g",
    "focused": 1513262627570,
    "isDuplicate": true,
    "categoryId": 15074,
    "colorId": 54
  }, {
    "order": 4,
    "name": "h",
    "shortName": "h",
    "isDuplicate": true,
    "categoryId": 15075,
    "colorId": 59
  }];
  var sorted, i;

  sorted = names.concat().sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.name > b.name)
      return 1;
    if (a.name < b.name)
      return -1;
    return 0;
  });
  for (i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    if (sorted[i].name !== '') {
      sorted[i].isDuplicate = ((sorted[i - 1] && sorted[i - 1].name === sorted[i].name)) || ((sorted[i + 1] && sorted[i + 1].name === sorted[i].name));
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can introduce a Generic function to sort the array of objects on basis of any key using the below function -

```js
$scope.sortByKey = function(array, key) {
    return array.sort(function(a, b) {
        var x = a[key]; var y = b[key];
        return ((x > y) ? -1 : ((x < y) ? 1 : 0));
    });
};
```

Using this function, you can sort the array of object on basis of any key and set the property "isLargest" to true. You can check the code snippet below.

```js
$scope.verifyDuplicate = function() {
  var names = [{
    "order": 1,
    "name": "a",
    "shortName": "a",
    "isDuplicate": false,
    "categoryId": 15070,
    "colorId": 50
  }, {
    "order": 2,
    "name": "s",
    "shortName": "s",
    "categoryId": 15071,
    "colorId": 51
  }, {
    "order": 3,
    "name": "h",
    "shortName": "g",
    "focused": 1513262627570,
    "isDuplicate": true,
    "categoryId": 15074,
    "colorId": 54
  }, {
    "order": 4,
    "name": "h",
    "shortName": "h",
    "isDuplicate": true,
    "categoryId": 15075,
    "colorId": 59
  }];
  
  var sorted;
  sorted = $scope.sortByKey(names , "colorId");
  
  //To check if the multiple object has largest value
   for(var i = 0; i< sorted.length;i++){
     if(sorted[i] === sorted[0]) sorted[i]["isLargestColorId"] = true;
     else break;
   }
  
};
```

Comment: this solution looks fine but can I combine it with my original code check for name duplicates?

Answer (score 1):

Make use of ES6 features

find biggerColorId object first then assign isBigger property is true

```js
 var names = [{
    "order": 1,
    "name": "a",
    "shortName": "a",
    "isDuplicate": false,
    "categoryId": 15070,
    "colorId": 50
  }, {
    "order": 2,
    "name": "s",
    "shortName": "s",
    "categoryId": 15071,
    "colorId": 51
  }, {
    "order": 3,
    "name": "h",
    "shortName": "g",
    "focused": 1513262627570,
    "isDuplicate": true,
    "categoryId": 15074,
    "colorId": 54
  }, {
    "order": 4,
    "name": "h",
    "shortName": "h",
    "isDuplicate": true,
    "categoryId": 15075,
    "colorId": 59
  }];

var biggerColorId = Math.max.apply(Math,names.map(function(o){return o.colorId;}))

var objOfBiggerColorId = names.find(function(o){ return o.colorId == biggerColorId; })

objOfBiggerColorId.isBigger = true; //set isbigger property true for biggerColorId

// alert(JSON.stringify(objOfBiggerColorId))
console.log('objOfBiggerColorId ' + JSON.stringify(objOfBiggerColorId))


// alert(JSON.stringify(names))
console.log('names ' + JSON.stringify(names))
```